# Why are ASP.NET MVC 3 exceptions being 'handled' twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I have implemented exception handling using below code.[Edited Start] I do not know why it is calling view twice. [Edited Done]

Basecontroller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

                if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))
                {
                    this.View("OutOfRange").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.View("Error").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
                }
            }

            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
        public ActionResult Exception2()
        {
            throw (new ArgumentOutOfRangeException());
        }

        public ActionResult Exception3()
        {
            throw (new Exception());
        }
}
```

Error View (Shared folder only)

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
    </h2>
    <h3>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <p>@Model.Exception.GetType().Name<br />
                thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName</p>
            <br />
            @Model.Exception
        }
    </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

OutOfRange view (Shared folder only)

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OutOfRange Exception</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <p>@Model.Exception.GetType().Name<br />
                    thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName</p>
                <br />
                @Model.Exception
            }
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Execution URL : `http://[domainName]/Home/Exception2`

Here it is working fine. [EDITED : Here it also call twice.]

[image]

Execution URL : `http://[domainName]/Home/Exception3`

**Here it is not working fine. You can see that "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." is coming twice. When I debugged the application using above URL, Error view called twice ( First time Model is null and second time Model contains some value). May I know what is wrong with my implementation?**
[image]

Comment: You are missing @model directive in second view.

Comment: @Colombo . Did not work for me.

Comment: Please publish the Controller method for Error view

Comment: @Colombo . No need to write any single Controller method for error view when we are using HandleErrorAttribute.

Comment: Try clean and rebuild the solution if you haven't already done that. I recommend you to have a look at ELMAH for error logging for ASP.NET /MVC3. Good luck!

Comment: @Colombo . There are many ways to implement exception handling in MVC. But I can say that I want to utilize in-built MVC attribute to implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things to try:

1. Remove the default `HandleError` global action filter attribute from your `Global.asax` if it is present. When you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application the default template registers it inside the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method. So comment out the line which registers this attribute.
2. Enable custom errors in your web.config:

   ```
   <customErrors mode="On" />
   ```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to pass a model to the `Error.cshtml` view (as it is strongly typed to `HandleErrorInfo`) you could do the following:

```
else
{
    string controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
    var result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "Error",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model)
    };
    filterContext.Result = result;
}
```

Comment: If i remove the HandleError than HandleErrorInfo model is coming null. :( .

Comment: Well, that's absolutely normal. I can't see you passing any model inside your custom `OnException` method. You just render the view. You need to pass a model to this view if you expect to get some model in it.

Comment: Hmmm.How do I get HandleErrorInfo in View ? Do i get this object in OnException override  method?

Comment: You are like my Godfather. It works!!! I learned a lot of things from your posts/blogs. Thanks a ton for it!!!

Comment: Just for the knowledge. When I am register HandleErrorAttribute in global.asax file using following code.                filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
{
    ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException),
    View = "OutOfRange",
    Order = 2
});                                                                  I have defined OutOfrange view in Shared folder but its looking it in "Home" view folder. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Add `base.OnException(filterContext);` before
`if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)`

```
      protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
      {
          base.OnException(filterContext);
         if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)

      }
```

Comment: I will try your solution and will let you know the output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I managed to resolve the error by adding:

```
Response.End();
```

To the end of my OnException method.

I know it's not the ideal resolution, but, it did at least get me out of a bind until such a time as I can investigate a more complete option.