# How to show catch exception message on view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, razor

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   System.Diagnostic.StackTrace st=New System.Diagnostic.StackTrace(ex,true);
   System.Diagnostic.StackFrame sf=st.getframe(st.frame-1);
   int irow=sf.GetFileLineNumber();
   int icol=sf.GetFileColumnNumber();
   string smsg="Row: "+irow+ " Col "+icol;
   Throw New Exception(smsg, ex);
}
```

This is the code I have written in my main method which is implementation of insert all values of excel sheet into database in mvc3 razor. Now, Please help me how will I show this exception message on view page?

Comment: Do you wanna find out exception details or show it to user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 : Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309635/mvc3-exception-handling)

Answer (score 5):

You can always insert the error message in the ViewBag and then show it in the view you display after. But maybe you want a more advanced solution?

```
ViewBag.MyExeption = theobjectcontainingtheerrorinfoyouwanttosee
```

Comment: keep in mind that this code has been written in main method . I have a separate folder which contain this method and a .exe file which is calling by controller.